# Satellite 5.7 (Spacewalk 2.3.2) not allowing scripts to be run from upload

Tags: apache-httpd, selinux, spacewalk, redhat-satellite

I'm trying to make my Satellite 5.7 server installation more secure. I'd like to turn off the function to run scripts from `https://mysatserver/pub/upload/up` without breaking Satellite.

The dir looks like this

```
-rw-r--r--. root   root   unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 index.html
drwxrwxr-x. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 up
-rw-r--r--. root   root   unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 upload.php
```

What I'd like to do is make sure that no scripts can be run under /up.

My thoughts are:

- Change selinux context type?
- Is there any settings in the Apache config files that would turn this off?

Comment: Look at your /var/log/audit/audit.log file and run it thorough audit2allow for the relevant module to allow access.

Comment: Hi @RamanSailopal thanks for the answer. But I'd like to remove the ability to run scripts in that dir. But I still need to be able to upload files there.